# Определение числа существительного в конкретном предложении

Tags: грамотная-речь, единственное-множественное-число, существительные

Подскажите, является ли ошибкой употребление слова "экскурсия" в единственном числе в предложении, где перечисляется несколько туристических объектов? Или нужно писать "экскурсий"?

Вот предложение:
Во время экскурсии из Бентоты туристам может быть предложено посетить следующие места:
• национальный заповедник Миннерия;
• храм в Дамбулле;
• водопад Рамбода.

Comment: Число не имеет значения, а вот «может быть предложено» вносит неопределённость: это о дополнительной оплате, о сезонности?